# Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2015 - Installation Error - Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Server.GrantConfigDBDatabaseAction failed

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015

Trying to install Dynamics CRM 2015 and I get the following error

[image]

**Action Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Server.GrantConfigDBDatabaseAccessAction failed. Windows NT user group of 'DEV\' not found. Check the name again.**

Not sure what the issue could be but I got the following in the error log:

05:01:05|   Info| Executing Sql Scripts ...
05:01:05|   Info| File = Scripts\Constants.sql, Message = Add required database constants to mimic enumerations, Target = All
05:01:07|   Info| File = Scripts\Constraints.sql, Message = Add required database constraints, Target = All
05:01:07|   Info| File = Scripts\GeoConstraints.sql, Message = Add required database constraints, Target = All
05:01:07|   Info| File = Scripts\Reserved.sql, Message = Add required reserved names for config database, Target = All
05:01:07|   Info| File = Scripts\Features.sql, Message = Add features., Target = All
05:01:07|   Info| File = Scripts\SecurityRolesOnPremiseAndSPLA.sql, Message = Add pre-defined security roles, Target = OnPremise, SPLA
05:01:07|   Info| File = Scripts\PrivilegesOnPremiseAndSPLA.sql, Message = Add pre-defined security privileges, Target = OnPremise, SPLA
05:01:07|   Info| File = Scripts\GeoConstants.sql, Message = Geo constants for All SKU, Target = All
05:01:07|   Info| File = Scripts\OnPremSPLAConstants.sql, Message = Site-Wide constants for OnPrem and SPLA, Target = OnPremise, SPLA
05:01:07|   Info| File = Scripts\NotificationIndex.sql, Message = Update Notification table with CreatedOn index, Target = All
05:01:07|   Info| Installing Sql Jobs ...
05:01:07|   Info| Name = .SiteWideCleanup, Description = Add site-wide cleanup job, Target = OnPremise, SPLA
05:02:09|   Info| Updated Yammer settings for OnPremise installation
05:02:09|   Info| CrmAction execution time; InstallConfigDatabaseAction; 00:01:11.5354101
05:02:09|   Info| Executing Install action: Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Server.ConfigureClaimsAction
05:02:09|   Info| CrmAction execution time; ConfigureClaimsAction; 00:00:00.1093760
05:02:09|   Info| Executing Install action: Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Server.GrantConfigDBDatabaseAccessAction
05:02:09|  Error| System.Exception: Action Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Server.GrantConfigDBDatabaseAccessAction failed. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Windows NT user or group 'DEV\' not found. Check the name again.
   at Microsoft.Crm.DatabaseInstaller.Common.SharedDatabaseUtility.GrantDBAccess(String sqlServerName, String databaseName, String groupName, CrmDBConnectionType connectionType)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Server.GrantConfigDBDatabaseAccessAction.Do(IDictionary parameters)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Shared.CrmAction.ExecuteAction(CrmAction action, IDictionary parameters, Boolean undo)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---, Error, RetryCancel, Option1

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What user are you installing as? Do they have SysAdmin privs in SQL?

Comment: Both the installation account and the deployment web service account are domain accounts with local admin access and sysadmin privs to the database.

Answer (score 0):

This will happen if you are logged in to multiple systems with the same account.  Try logging out of any other system that you might be logged into with the account in question, as well as close SQL Server Management Studio if logged in with the same account, and then retry the installation again.

For more details, see the Dynamics Community solution:

https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/microsoft-dynamics-crm-forum/274391/ms-dynamics-365-on-premise-installation-issue-microsoft-crm-setup-server-grantconfigdbdatabaseaccessaction-failed-windows-nt-user-or-group-mydomain-sqlaccessgroup-not-found-check-the-name-again/781092